# Create dynamic ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist, dynamic-arrays

I have a problem related to "dynamic ArrayLists". I have a List that contains usernames and their data. I want for every distinct username to create a single list that contains all data of this user. For example, I have an arraylist (username,tweet) that has: lefteris,"Plays ball", Kostas, "Plays basketball", lefteris, "Nice weather". And I want after that to create two lists. One list with kostas and his tweets and another with lefteris and its tweets (2 tweets). The parent arraylist may have 20 distinct usernames or more. How can I do that ?

Comment: dude, `ArrayList` is already dynamic...  using `dynamic` is redundant

Comment: I mean that i want to make different arraylists from the parrent arraylist based on username... If i have 2 different usernames i want to have two arraylists.

Comment: Are you restricted to that implementation (list of user-tweet) or can you improve that?

Comment: Then a hasmap where username would be the key, and list the value; would be a solution.

Comment: No.. i parse the data from txt. If i use hashmap, if there are two similar username, then the first would be replaced with the second and etc..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use hashmap or hashset instead because if you need to store something in pairs, hashing is a perfect solution......

Comment: i parse the data from txt. If i use hashmap, if there are two similar username, then the first would be replaced with the second and etc

Comment: but how do you identify the different 'users' then?

Comment: Based on their username. One user might have 5 different tweets. I want to store this user and his tweets to an arraylist, so i can compare users (similarity) after this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the following data structure:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>
```

Then you could manipulate a "dynamic" list of properties keyed to each name, if the properties are single items:

```
Lefteris->("Plays ball", "Nice weather",...)
Kostas->("Plays basketball",...)
```

If the properties are key-value pairs, do:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>>
```

Data looking like:

```
Lefteris->(Sport->"Plays ball", Weather->"Nice",...)
Kostas->(Sport->"basketball",...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you parse the items from a file, you can do the following.

Create a map that contains the tweets associated to a particular username

```
Map<String,List<String>> userTweets = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

Then, have a method to associate a tweet to certain user, verifying that it is already added in the map and adding it if it isn't.

```
public void addTweetToUser(String user, String tweet) {
    if(userTweets.containsKey(user))
        userTweets.get(user).add(tweet);
    else {
        List<String> newUserTweets = new LinkedList<String>();
        newUserTweets.add(tweet);
        userTweets.put(user, newUserTweets);
    }
}
```

As a plus, you can improve this by creating an object `UserTweet` that contains:

```
public class UserTweet {
    private String user;
    private String tweet;

    //Constructor, Setters & Getters or all of them
}
```

Then your `addTweetToUser` method can have an `UserTweet` parameter instead.

When you want to know the tweets for a certain user, you just obtain the corresponding list from the `userTweets` map. I alsomethods to remove tweets and/or remove users, just in case.

Comment: Thanks @Gamb , I am trying to implement this. Sounds good. I will keep the form updated about the results.

Comment: @Gamp Is it easy to do something like double for to this map? i.e in an arraylist you can do `for (int q = 0; q < data.size(); q++) {
                for (int h = 1; h < data.size(); h++) {
}}`

Comment: As in replacing the map with a structure you can iterate through with a double for? It's doable but it'll cost you in terms of performance. Pay special attention to the indexes of your double for, i.e. what's the connection between q and h.

Answer (score 0):

Several libraries add excellent collection-processing functionality to Java along the lines of what functional languages provide. One such library is [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Guava provides a [MultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) suitable for grouping things the way you want. There are also many utility methods, like [MultiMaps.index()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29), which collects items from a list into a map by applying some function to the elements of the list to calculate a key. With such support, it only takes a few lines of code and one [Function](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) implementation (a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) in any other language) to solve your problem:

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimaps;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Tweets {
    public static final int NAME = 0;
    public static final int TWEET = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> namesAndTweets = Arrays.asList(
            "lefteris", "Plays ball", 
            "Kostas", "Plays basketball", 
            "lefteris", "Nice weather");
        List<List<String>> nameTweetPairs = 
            Lists.partition(namesAndTweets, 2);
        Multimap<String, List<String>> namesAndTweetsByName =
            Multimaps.index(nameTweetPairs, get(NAME));
        Multimap<String, String> tweetsByName =
            Multimaps.transformValues(namesAndTweetsByName, get(TWEET));
        System.out.println(tweetsByName);
    }

    private static Function<List<String>, String> get(final int n) {
        return new Function<List<String>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(List<String> nameAndTweet) {
                return nameAndTweet.get(n);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
{lefteris=[Plays ball, Nice weather], Kostas=[Plays basketball]}
```

**Update:** To explain the code a bit more, there are three basic steps:

1. Take the list that has names and tweets all mixed together and use [Lists.partition()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition%28java.util.List,%20int%29) to break it into pairs of (name, tweet).
2. Use MultiMaps.index() to build a MultiMap from the pairs, taking the name as the map key. This gives you a map where map keys are names and map values are the (name, tweet) pairs.
3. Use [MultiMaps.transformValues()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#transformValues%28com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) to reduce the map values from (name, tweet) pairs to just the tweets.

P.S. does anyone know if there's a built-in Function that does what my `get()` does? It seems like a useful Function that should be provided, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: `NAME` is a constant defined at the top of the class with a value of 0. `get()` is the method at the bottom of the class that returns a `Function` that gets element `n` from a `List`.

Comment: I also updated my answer with an explanation of the steps being taken.

Comment: you can do Function<List<CompareUsers>, String> instead of  Function<List<String>, String> if you have this type of list eh?

Comment: I don't know what CompareUsers is, but the two type parameters of a Function are the type of input and type of output, so you can put whatever's appropriate there.